# How to add a flow in Opendaylight to drop HTTP traffic

Tags: mininet, opendaylight

I'm very new to mininet and open daylight.

I have a custom topology created and pinball works successfully

I have HTTP server running on H3 and I can do wget from H1

I need to show I can update flows on the switches using the controller

my theory was to create flow-on open daylight to tell the switches to drop HTTP traffic (i have a screenshot of the Wget working if I can screenshot the flow and then it not working that's enough)

I looked online and I've got to Yangon, then sal-flow and Add flow, but I have no idea what to put in all the boxes e.g.:

```
Flow-ref

Transcation-uri

flow-table

node

container-name

cookie_mask

buffer_id

out_port

out_group

flags

flow-name

installHw (True/False)

barrier (True/False)

strict (True/False)

priorty

idle-timeout

hardtimeout

cookie

table_id
```

any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

maybe this page can help:

https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/openflowplugin/en/latest/users/flow-examples.html#ethernet-src-dest-addresses-ipv4-src-dest-addresses-tcp-src

you could match on tcp-destination-port using 80 and have the action be to
drop. I think with mininet you can just use table 0 and some high priority
value so the rule will be processed first.